# Father's approval for UK Tier 2 dependent visa for my 2-month old baby

Tags: uk-visa, dependent-visa, children, egyptian-citizens

I am the main tier 2 applicant, I have a two-month old baby. He is my dependent. I live inEgypt, my husband lives in gulf. We are not divorced but he is absent from our life.

He included in marriage certificate a clear formal witnessed approval for-me to take baby anywhere outside Egypt.

Is this certificate enough or do I need further approval from him?

Comment: There are two issues here: getting the visa, and exiting Egypt. As to the first: what does the Tier 2 visa application require vis-a-vis minor children? As to the second: the airline may demand proof of your legal right to take the baby out of Egypt, which proof may be different from or in addition to the visa requirements. Without evidence satisfactory to the airline, the airline won't permit your baby to board. Ask the airline what they will require.